# How to enable/disable button when I select a row in datatable using primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<p-header>
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
        List of Impound Vehicle
        <button pButton type="button" (click)="showDialog(0)" style="float: right" icon="fa-save" class="ui-button-primary" label="Release"></button>

    </div>
</p-header>

<p-column field="empAddress" header="Address" [style]="{'width':'150px'}" [sortable]="true" [filter]="checked" filterPlaceholder=""></p-column>
<p-column field="empGender" header="Gender" [style]="{'width':'100px'}"></p-column>


<p-column header="Action" [style]="{'width':'100px'}">
    <ng-template let-viotor="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-list-ul" class="ui-button-success"></button>
        <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-trash-o" class="ui-button-danger"></button>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorLeft">
    There are {{impoundList?.length}} impoundList recorded.
</ng-template>
```

Can I enable/disable the release button when I click a row in the datatable.. So can anyone help to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a disabled property to the button

```
<button pButton type="button" [disabled]="isButtonDisabled"(click)="showDialog(0)" style="float: right" icon="fa-save" class="ui-button-primary" label="Release"></button>
```

Assign a click event to the columns and call a function and change the button enable/disable flag.  I havent used a datatable, but for turbo table this is one of the approach.

Eg :

```
<tr>
          <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="true" (click)="changeButtonStatus();">
...
          </td>
<tr>
```

In component

```
isButtonDisabled:boolean=true;

function changeButtonStatus(){
this.isButtonDisabled= true/false ( based on your logic).
}
```